# Current control loop compensation network

Tags: mosfet, analog, gate-driving, inrush-current, compensation

I have an application that uses n-channel Mosfet as a high-side switch controlled by an IC driver. The point of the Mosfet is to manage the inrush current to the load. I understand that the resistor R<sub>1</sub> is there to prevent oscillations, but I'm not sure if I understand the rest of the circuitry connected to the gate of the Mosfet the right way.

I see the purpose of the C<sub>2</sub> as an "additional" capacitance to increase the low internal Mosfet Gate capacitance to control the inrush current / managing the slew rate. But what's the point of R<sub>2</sub>?

I read that the R<sub>2</sub> + C<sub>2</sub> form a compensation network to compensate for the current control loop. If this is true, could anyone please explain how exactly it works?

[image]

Comment: My schematic is only conceptual of course but correct. The entire schematic is on the last page number 22 (Driver IC documentation). see the Mosfet named MH  [LINK](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4227fa.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your R2 and C2 are used when the MOSFET (your M1) has a gate-source capacitance less than 2 nF. In the data sheet R2 is called \$R_{HG}\$ and C2 is called \$C_{HG}\$: -

[image]

And, the text from the data sheet says this: -

[image]

So, yes they are required for compensation (when the MOSFET gate capacitance is below 2 nF) and, together, they mimic the presence of a bigger MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. I was  confused by that "current control loop" term and expected there was also some other magic. Maybe one more question about that R2 (RHG) resistor value. I see that IC documentation claims its range, but I see no reason why they choose exactly 47 OHM in their example. Should I see the value of R2 (RHG) as an empirically chosen value, because it just works for them? Is there any generic analytical way to find its optimal value? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is any mathematical relationship you can derive. It's case of following the data sheet. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).